# How to prevent minikube cluster from running at startup?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm using minikube/ kubectl on Ubuntu 16.04, trying to keep minikube cluster from running at startup. Is there a service I can disable for the same?

Comment: Depending on your setup, you can have a 'localkube' service you can stop. or it is a virtualbox you can stop.

Comment: @wargre Thanks for replying. I looked for a localkube service but no luck.. And I'm not using VirtualBox either. I'm using Docker instead of a hypervisor by setting vm-driver=none. It's running the cluster at startup therefore starting a bunch of containers.

Comment: Then the service is lokalkube I think.

Comment: can't you just execute 'minikube stop' when you stop working on it, I think it will not start when you reboot later

Comment: @lvthillo it does

Answer (score 7):

Try `systemctl disable kubelet.service`

I use the same setup on Ubuntu 18.04 and had the same issue.
After starting minikube without virtualization using `sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none` I can stop it with `sudo minikube stop` but after reboot the cluster is up again.

For me it was `kubelet` running on my machine that would start the cluster on reboot.
`systemctl disable kubelet.service` fixed the issue.

You can check if `kubelet` is enabled on your machine by running `systemctl is-active kubelet`

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed minikube you could try to disable it in rc.conf

```
sudo update-rc.d minikube disable
```

or

```
sudo update-rc.d minikube remove
```

For further detail look at the man page for update-rc.d by typing the command `man update-rc.d`